# formula field in crystal report not working well when if condition is apply.how i solve the issue?

Tags: crystal-reports, conditional-statements

I have three columns in which two columns (`Available` and `Minimum Level`) are from dataset and third column (`Status`) is a formula field. My requirement is that when `available` is greater than `minimum` then `status` would "NO" else "YES". I make formula as following:

```
if {DataTable1.available}>{DataTable1.minimum} then
    "NO"
else 
    "YES"
```

Its output displays below figure. It works well when available "0". If more than "0" then not working well as it shows in red area. It should display "YES" because `available` is less than `minimum`.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the values you are comparing are string values, not numeric values.

You can convert the string values to a numeric value using `ToNumber`:

```
IF ToNumber({DataTable1.available}) > ToNumber({DataTable1.minimum}) THEN
  "NO"
ELSE
  "YES"
```

You can also define the columns `available` and `minimum` of `DataTable1` with a numeric data type.